# How to Stop bind local intent service

Tags: android, intentservice, android-service-binding

I have made the Intent service and designed it in such a way that it has capability of restart itself if killed by the OS , but if it is stopped by user it must have stop.

Every thing was going good. But Problem occured when I tried to implement message handler and Binding techniques.

**What I have done**

My sole purpose was getting the status from the service (which in my case is intent service) and update my views. For this I have implemented Message handler and start to bound the service .

I am binding my service in such a way

```
 //This is my interface to get specific call back in activity
        mReceiver = new DownloadResultReceiver(new Handler());
        mReceiver.setReceiver(ListSuitClass.this);
        serviceIntent = new Intent(DownloadService.ALARM_SERVICE);
        serviceIntent.setClass(ListClass.this, DownloadService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("receiver", mReceiver);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("requestId", 101);
        startService(serviceIntent);

    }
    if (!mIsBound) {
        bindService(serviceIntent, mConnection, BIND_DEBUG_UNBIND);
        mIsBound = true;
    }
```

**Problem**

I want to stop the service by stop button , But it stop for a while and starts over again . 
I do not know what I am doing wrong , And what is starting again the service.

Please help me in stopping the service.

> Note: I am running my service in a separate process.

Answer (score 0):

As per the code, `mIsBound` might be the local variable of `Activity`. When you stop your activity and restart it, it will have the default value of boolean i.e. false and so `bindService` is called again and again. What you need to do is either make it static variable or store the service bind status in `SharedPreferences` and read value from it.

Comment: your guess is right , but that code is on button on startService

Comment: Actually let me tell you a little story , I am downloading images in service. I want to start the service when user click on download images button , I want this process to be start in service , and user can get status in a specified area, He may see 3 out of 10 images downloaded. and thus after starting service , the start service button should change in the stop service

Comment: I have done all the things and every thing is working , but when i hit stop service button , it start my service again . :( after stopping it .